# Trying to highlight a word with red in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, action

I have an adobe pdf document that I am creating where I am creating links from one page to another. In my JavaScript code below, I am searching for "120" (word == "120"). What I want to have happen is this...when the end user clicks on their initial link and is taken to the page where this text appears, I want the text to be highlighted in "red" so the callout on a drawing is easy to spot amongst many many other callout numbers. I don't want to change the text to red...I want to highlight it but I cannot figure out how to do that.

The `if (nWait == "0")` statement is inserted for the instances where I have more than one location within the pdf page with the same word that I am looking for.

Here is the code I have been working with, this is inserted into my adobe pdf with their Run a JavaScript Action. I'm completely lost, can someone help me out here?

```js
nWait = 0;
nWords = getPageNumWords(85);
for (var loop = 0; loop < [nWords - 1]; loop++) {
  word = getPageNthWord(85, loop);
  if (word == "1") {
    if (nWait == "0") {
      this.selectPageNthWord(85, loop);
      break;
    }
    nWait = nWait + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `loop < nWords` instead, you're creating an array.

Comment: Ok, I'm just trying to understand...newbie here. I have a technical manual that I'm working in where I have a part number in a list, on one page that I need to link to a specific call-out on another page (just to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.) I can do this successfully with what I have posted, the code works fine to find what I want (perhaps not the most succinct way to do it I'm sure lol.) I'd simply like to change the color of the background of the text when it is found.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run this in Acrobat, but this should get you closer to your goal. If I understand what you want to accomplish, you only want to select one word. Your `nWait` variable isn't necessary for that, just use `break` to break out of the loop after you've found what you were looking for.

```js
// Get the number of words on the page
var nWords = getPageNumWords(85);

// Loop over all of them. Your end-condition of the loop should just be `nWords` in this case. If the number of words is 5, your loop is going to run from 0 to 4, which is 5 times (which is what you want).
for (var loop = 0; loop < nWords; loop++) {

  // Get the word from Acrobat
  var word = getPageNthWord(85, loop);

  // If this word is what we're looking for...
  if (word === "1") {

    // Select it on the page, and then break the loop as we're done
    this.selectPageNthWord(85, loop);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the code I posted works for me in my pdf's....it finds what I want it to find. The problem is that I want to change the default color that is used for highlighting the search result when the link is clicked. It defaults to a blue which gets lost in what I am working in and I can't figure out how to change that...Adobe is of NO help. I want to change that to red. I may not need the nWait variable....but it seems to help when I have more than one callout in my drawing with the same number. With that I can direct it to exactly where I want it to go.